# What is the grammatical function of “while the wind beats against the window and the lamp is burning”

Tags: clauses

> "And indeed, what is better than to sit by one’s fireside in the evening with a book, **while the wind beats against the window and the lamp is burning?**" ― Gustave Flaubert, *Madame Bovary*

What grammatical phrase may you dictate *while wind beats against the window and the lamp is burning*? May it seem an adverbial clause placing information on when? I thought a comma gets placed when independent clauses go former to dependent clauses?

May you write it like this?

> **While the wind beats against the window and the lamp is burning**, what is better than to sit by one's fireside in the evening with a book?

Comment: Yes it is an adverbial. There is a comma in the sentence, so I don't know why you're asking about that. Last, yes you can rewrite the sentence the way you did.

Comment: Commas are mere typographic conventions that attempt to represent something about the language.  Clause-boundaries are part of (the) language itself. It is possible to start the sentence with that while-clause, or to end the sentence with it. Whether to use a comma, or not, is determined by Donald Trump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an adverbial, and in theory it could fall in either position. But if you swap the clauses you change an important aspect of the meaning.

In the original, Léon asks the rhetorical question in order to express the pleasure he and Emma take in reading, and then he adds a clause which describes circumstances which make reading even more pleasurable. This sequence lends an extra dimension to the clause *While the wind beats &c*; it could be thought of as meaning *Reading is **especially** pleasurable while the wind beats*.

But if you put that clause first, it loses that sense of something extra. It is taken to define the particular circumstances under which reading is pleasurable; in effect, it becomes a condition clause, approximately equivalent to ***If*** the wind beats &c. It moves toward implying that  *Reading is **only** pleasurable while the wind beats*.